# Selenium with Python cannot find button element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, browser-automation

So i'm trying to use Selenium to click the following search bar button:

```
<input name="someName" type="button" id="buttonid" value="Search" class="btn-primary" style="margin-bottom:9px">
```

I'm getting the error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="buttonid"]"}
```

when I try to run:

```
search_button = driver.find_element(By.ID, "buttonid")
```

I also tried this:

```
search_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "buttonid")))
```

but it gives me a timeout exception. Implicitly waiting doesn't help either.

Has someone an idea what I am missing?

Comment: What's the url, and is it publicly accessible? if not, can you post **full* html of the page?

Answer (score 0):

As it seem, it is a search box or other something like this.
Try
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "btn-primary")

Comment: That gives me the same error: 
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":". btn-primary"}

Comment: Send an image of the box please

Answer (score 0):

So I think i found the problem. The search bar and search button is apparently in an iframe and thats why I can't find the elements.